# differentiate the terms deductive system, model/structure, formal system, first-order logic

Tags: logic, incompleteness, first-order-logic, foundations, peano-axioms

I can not bring the terms deductive system, model/structure, formal system, first-order logic into order in my head ;-) It seems to me that they are not overly used in a consistent manner and sometimes even have different meanings. Maybe you can help me to sort it out in my brain ;-)

The *deductive system* (DS) is the syntactical manipulation mechanism, which allows formal deductions (i.e. something like Hilbert calculus). So we can decide something like $A \vdash_{DS} B$.

While a *model/structure* (M) gives semantic meaning to the formal language, i.e. allows for semantic truth interpretation of sentences. So we can decide something like $A \models_{M} B$.

A *formal system* then is the triple of a particular deductive system, a particular model and a formal language?

If talking about *first-order logic* we just mean the formal language together with one deductive system and a model/structure. So actually the characteristics, when talking about *first-order logic* is the available language, symbols, etc?

Comment: Try asking one more clearly focused question at a time, if you want useful answers.

Comment: @Peter Smith: I tried and edited my post. Sorry!

Comment: logisches durcheinander: Thanks! I have tried to answer the shorter question.

Answer (score 1):

When people say "first-order logic" they mean a logic that has a certain kind of language (built up from function symbols and relation symbols in the usual way), a certain kind of deductive system, and a certain semantics using structures. There are many variations that are all called "first-order logic", but they all behave in generally the same way.

The key aspects of first-order logic, apart from the specific kind of language, are that it has several key properties:

- Soundness: If a formula is provable, it is true in every structure (for the same language)
- Completeness: If a formula is true in every structure for its language, then the formula is provable
- Compactness: If a formula is a consequence of an infinite set $A$ of formulas, it is a consequence of some finite subset $F$ of $A$.
- The [Löwenheim–Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem)

All the systems that people call "first order logic" will have these properties.

Comment: Thank. Is it "for every _possible_ structure" or "for every structure _considered_ when talking about what is called first-order logic"? What are the _certain kinds_ of language, deductive system and semantics -- are they defined by saying "first-order logic" or does every "first-order logic" have it's own certain language, deductive system and model?

Comment: Once a particular first-order language $L$ is fixed, there is an unambiguous definition of a "structure for the language $L$". When people say every possible structure, they always mean every possible "structure for the language $L$", where that quoted phrase has its formal definition. However, the concept of "structure for a language $L$" is sufficiently general that it covers everything we normally think about when we think about giving interpretations to the symbols of $L$ - any concrete informal interpretation can be converted to a "structure for the language $L$" in the formal sense.

Comment: So actually, if I pin down a first-order language $L$ and choose which deductive system to use (e.g. natural deduction), I've settled what the "first-order logic" is I am working with and also possible structures for that language have been fixed then? So choosing a language and a particular decutive system determines the set of structures. If if additionally has the four mentioned key properties, I would call that the "first-order logic" I use?

Comment: As soon as you choose the language, the set of structures is already determined. There is a definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_%28mathematical_logic%29 or in any logic text. The choice of a deductive system is also determined. So really, if you know you want a first-order logic, all you have to choose is the language (also called the signature) and everything else is already defined by the general definitions for first-order logic. You can choose what *kind* of deductive system you want, but all the ones for first-order logic prove the same formulas ...

Comment: ... namely, they prove a formula in a language $L$ if and only if that formula is true in every "structure for the language $L$".

Comment: Ok, so "first-order logic" means picking one signature. This determines the set of structures and the deductive systems. Does it per se have the four mentioned key properties or is having these what makes a first-order logic a first-order logic?

So when Gödel proved "completeness of first-order logic" he pinned down one signature, choose the Hilbert calculus (since all deductive systems prove the same formulas), and hence showed completeness for that first-order logic with that signature?

Comment: The proof of completeness is for an arbitrary signature and a fixed deduction system, so it has to be re-proved for each deductive system. That has been done for all the standard systems: particular Hilbert-style systems, natural deduction systems, tableau systems, etc., that can be looked up in a textbook. All of these have the above properties for an arbitrary signature, which is one reason that first-order logic is so flexible.

Comment: Wow, many thanks! Some details are now clarified in my head. As you remember there were a lot more questions in the original post, I'll see how I can have them independent from that post here..